# Script google sheets form autocomplete and fill cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a form with an input type "text" which has an autofill function from a list that is fed from a spreadsheet in google drive (this works fine); by selecting the desired option from the list; I want another field in the form to be filled automatically with the cell next to the right, that is, if I select the data (character string) of cell I5 with the auto-complete option, the new text field should be filled automatically with the contents of cell J5 (this does not work). The event I use does not capture the entire string of cell I5, but only the typed characters, can anyone help me?

I have this code:

```
 //page-js.html
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
 document.getElementById("redIps").addEventListener("blur",getRegimenIps);
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateRed).getRed();
 });

 //page-js.html
 function getRegimenIps(){
    var redIpsStr = document.getElementById("redIps").value;//****not capture the entire string***
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateIpsReg).getIpsReg(redIpsStr);
  }

 //page-js.html
 function updateIpsReg(regimen){
          document.getElementById("redIpsReg").value = regimen;
          M.updateTextFields();
      }

  //funcs.gs
  function getRed(){ //****This works fine ****
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("listas");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,9).getDataRegion().getValues();
  var options = {};
  data.forEach(function(v){
  options[v[0]]=null;
  });
  return options
}
//funcs.gs
function getIpsReg(redIpsStr){ //****This does not work****
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("listas");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,9,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var redIpsList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var regList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  
  console.log(redIpsStr);
  
  var position = redIpsList.indexOf(redIpsStr);
  if (position > -1){
      return regList[position].toFixed(2);
  }else{
      return 'Unavailable';
  }
}//end getIpsReg(redIpsStr)
```

Comment: I am not sure how your current code is supposed to work since you mix Javascript code parts (e.g. document.addEventListener) with Apps Script requests (e.g. calls to SpreadsheetApp) together in one code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ... the code corresponds to a form that is built in "script.google.com" and is embedded (url like "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKf........) in google sites. The form reads and writes records on google sheets.

Comment: I added a comment in each code snippet, indicating the file it belongs to